# The Gelocation API will change the location if the user will change his location?

Tags: jquery, api

I using `geolocation API` to get current location of the user, but once allowed share my location then it will not be asked again. But if my location will change then `geolocation API` give me old location or new location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Got it my answer, if you want to track location then need to use `watchPosition`

Please find below code for track your location

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```